# Topological sort on an incidence matrice

Tags: sorting, graph-algorithm

If my directed graph is represented as its incidence matrix how do I apply topological sort on that graph? I think it can be done by finding null rows and removing them with their corresponding columns but this is not efficient.How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: this question is really more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is homework.  Try the following algorithm:

1) Identify all of the nodes with indegree 0 (no edge points into the node)

2) For each node from step 1, perform a depth-first-search walk starting from the node.

If the graph is a DAG (directed acyclic graph -- no directed cycles like A -> B, B -> C, C -> A), the order in which you see nodes is guaranteed to be a topological ordering.